# Mapping increasing rank to decreasing but non-negative points

Tags: php, function, math, business-logic

I need to create a business logic or php function to compute the following: given some input `$rank` (which is the alexa ranking) I need to compute some `$points` in such a way that `$points` will be high for the top ranking website and will decrease with increasing `$rank` value.

I imagine something like this:

```
function($rank)
{
    $points = x*$rank;
    return $points;
}
```

How do I get `$points` in such a way that

- if the rank is 1 then the points returned is maximum (e.g. 10000).
- if rank is 2 then `$points` returned will be 9500 or nearby.
- if rank is 4 then `$points` returned will be 6000 or nearby.
- if rank is 200 `$points` returned will be 2 or whatever the function will return.

Rule: if `$rank` is less then `$points` should be more. Maximal value of `$points` is 10000 which is for `$rank=1`.

Now as the `$rank` increases the `$points` value should decrease accordingly.

Comment: Do you require `$points` to be positive, or non-negative? Do you neet it to be integral?

Answer (score 0):

There are many formulas which might satisfy your requiremements.

## Nested powers

One possibility:

```
$points = 10000 * pow(0.993575964272119, pow($rank, 3.16332422407427) - 1)
```

This gives you the following [results](http://ideone.com/bgtj7f):

```
f(1) = 10000
f(2) = 9500
f(4) = 6000
f(9) = 12.065
f(10) = 0.84341
f(200) = 0
```

So the three values you fixed (1, 2 and 4) are all satisfied, but the result for 200 indicates that this might not be exactly what you're looking for. The curve looks like this:

[image: function graph]

By the way, I found this using python and mpmath, by fixing the form of the formula and determining the numbers with the many digits numerically:

```py
>>> import mpmath
>>> print(mpmath.findroot((lambda a,b: 10000*a**(2**b - 1) - 9500,
...                        lambda a,b: 10000*a**(4**b - 1) - 6000),
...                       (0.995, 2.7)))
[0.993575964272119]
[ 3.16332422407427]
```

If you decide on a different form of the function, this approach might be adapted.

## Exp of a polynomial

A possible different form with the desired properties would be this:

```
$points = exp(9.14265175282929 + $rank*(0.127179575914116 - $rank*0.0594909567672230))
```

This does not decrease quite as quickly as the one above:

```
f(  1) = 10000
f(  2) =  9500
f(  4) =  6000
f( 13) =     2.1002
f( 14) =     0.47852
f(200) =     0
```

It was obtained by solving this system of equations:

```
a +  b +   c = log(10000)
a + 2b +  4c = log( 9500)
a + 4b + 16c = log( 6000)
```

to obtain the coefficients *a* through *c* for the polynomial. One can add another degree to match `f(200)=2` as well, but in that case, the last coefficient will become positive, which means that points will start to increase with rank for very large ranks.

If you want to match that `f(200)=2` as well, you can do so using

```
$points = exp(max(8.86291000469285 - $rank*0.0408488141206645,
    9.14265175282929 + $rank*(0.127179575914116 - $rank*0.0594909567672230)))
```

although this will result in a bend in your curve.

To compare these alternatives to the above:

[image: Comparison of functions]

Answer (score 0):

```
    function getPoints($rank)
{
    $returnValue =  -0.005 * $rank * $rank - 0.035 * $rank + 100.040;
    if ($returnValue < 0) $returnValue = 0;
    return $returnValue;
}
```

This was my thinking.

Function is not forking for large values:
it should atleast give some small value for large ranks...
like if rank is 2000000 then points will be 2.
Thnx btw